# How to route the call (destined to Mobile number) to the RESTCOMM platform

Tags: restcomm

If a Person-A makes an outbound call either from land line or mobile to  Person-B’s Mobile number, how can we route the call first to a hosted RESTCOMM platform?  The idea here is that I would like to play an IVR option or a greeting or some kind of message through a RESTCOMM App before connecting the call onto the actual Mobile.

So far as per my research on RESTCOMM, following points are needed…
1)  To configure Outbound Proxy on RESTCOMM with NEXMO or VOIP INNOVATIONS.
2)  To register the Person-B’s Mobile number as an incoming phone number on RESTCOMM and then map it to the IVR App or Announcement App ( designed via RVD).

But how can we route the dialled call to Person-B’s Mobile number to RESTCOMM platform so that we can play the App.

Thanks in advance.

Ias M

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your scenario correctly what you need to do is:

1. Setup a **new** number (i.e. C) from Restcomm that will be the recepient for B's incoming calls (this would be internally allocated from a SIP provider like nexmo, or any other).
2. Attach a Restcomm application to that number that will greet the caller with a message or any other logic you want.
3. Have the Restcomm App forward the call to B's Cell number.

Notice that you can't register Person-B’s Mobile number as an incoming phone number on Restcomm as that number is already allocated for your phone and your phone alone by your Mobile Operator. You need a new number (i.e. C) that will receive the call at Restcomm and then execute any logic (like calling B)

Best regards,
Antonis

Comment: Ok.  So we need to configure NEXMO to forward the calls ( destined for Person-B's Mobile number) to this new C-Number on RESTCOMM.  But it means when person-A calls Person-B's Mobile number (which is allocated by the Person-B' Mobile Network Operator) then that call should get routed to NEXMO for it to be able to forward it  on to our C-Number. Then i think this means NEXMO would have got necessary arrangements in place with mobile network operators for this. Also we need to do appropriate NEXMO configuration to map Person-B number to the C-number on Restcomm for all this to happen.

Comment: In order to make calls towards B be routed to nexmo, then you need to enable a mobile operator call forwarding feature which I think would defeat your whole purpose. What we usually do instead, as discussed above, is to introduce a new number that is routed to Restcomm, which becomes your Restcomm Application number and which you can program however you see fit. For example you can play an announcement and then forward to B, or you can gather DTMF tones in order to decide where to forward, etc. Hope this helps.

Comment: hi is there any possibility that i can request your time for quick call with you as i would like to clarify few points about this. thanks in advance